# I have a problem in my MySQL function to compare integers

Tags: mysql, sql, function, database-design, compare

I hope your help for this problem. I created a table in Mysql named "Producto" (product in spanish, my database names are in Spanish) with attributes nombre (name), stock (stock) and precio (price), and I created a function that calculates the available stock of a product and compare with a quantity as parameter. Return 0 if stock is less than function parameter "can" (the requested quantity), and 1 if stock is greater.

```
    CREATE TABLE producto
    (
    id_producto INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    stock INT NOT NULL CHECK (stock > 0),
    precio DOUBLE(6,2) NOT NULL CHECK (precio > 0)
    );
```

This is my function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_consultar_stock(nom VARCHAR(50), can INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE v_can INT;
DECLARE v_valor INT;
SELECT stock INTO v_can FROM producto WHERE nombre = nom;
IF v_can > can THEN
    SET v_valor = 1;
ELSE
    SET v_valor = 0;
END IF;
RETURN v_valor;
END;
```

Before execute the function creation, MySql return me this error

```
`22:15:04
CREATE FUNCTION f_consultar_stock(nom VARCHAR(50), can INT) RETURNS INT BEGIN DECLARE v_can INT
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
0,00030 sec`
```

What is the cause? Please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can radically simplify the logic, by not using any local variables at all:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_consultar_stock (
    in_nom VARCHAR(50),
    in_can INT
)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT p.stock > in_can FROM producto p WHERE p.nombre = in_nom);
END;
```

Note the use of prefixes for the parameters of the function.  One common problem with stored procedures/functions in MySQL is that the parameter names conflict with column names.  Using prefixes such as `in_` and `out_` helps to avoid such conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

add delimiter also, you can simplify it to this :

```
delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION f_consultar_stock(nom VARCHAR(50), can INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE v_valor INT;
set v_valor = 0;
IF (SELECT stock FROM producto WHERE nombre = nom) > can THEN
    SET v_valor = 1;
ELSE
    SET v_valor = 0;
END IF;
RETURN v_valor;
END //
```

you even can simplify it more by not using v_valor var and return the value directly